# CSS style not applied unless I specify the exact selector

Tags: css

I've got this situation I think is weird, where

```
a:hover {
    color: #FD5454;
}
```

doesn't work, but

```
#feed h3 a:hover {
    color: #FD5454;
}
```

does. It has been some time since I used CSS extensively, so I have no idea why. Could someone please explain this to me? It surely must be a stupid question, but I just couldn't figure it out myself. Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
Here's the code it is affecting at the moment:

```
<div id="feed">
    <h2>Follow us on instagram</h2>
    <h3><a href="http://www.instagram.com/johndoe">@johndoe</a></h3>
</div>
```

And here are the complete style rules:

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#feed {
    text-align: center;
    background: url("../img/Feed_bg.jpg") center no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
}

#feed h2 {
    color: #789199;
    padding-top: 5vh;
}

#feed h3 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Lato Light";
    color: white;
}

/* This is working */
#feed h3 a:hover {
    color: #FD5454;
}

/* This is not */
a:hover {
    color: #FD5454;
}
```

Comment: Do you have other CSS rules that are taking precedence over the a:hover?

Comment: No. I have some other rules in which I use the :hover selector, but those are all affecting other elements.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] in your question please?

Comment: @j08691 Of course, my bad. I thought this was just a simple, stupid question. :)

Comment: See [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Specificity - How does “it” decide which styles to apply?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9133570/1529630)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case of [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Here, your `a:hover` selector isn't specific enough to override the `#feed h3 a` rule. As MDN notes:

> The following list of selector types is by increasing specificity:
>
> 1. Type selectors (e.g., h1) and pseudo-elements (e.g., :before).
> 2. Class selectors (e.g., .example), attributes selectors (e.g., [type="radio"]) and pseudo-classes (e.g., :hover).
> 3. ID selectors (e.g., #example).

And as you discovered, by adding `#feed` in front of your hover selector (`#feed a:hover`) increases the specificity to override the other selector.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ozLpp1mj/)**

There are many [CSS specificity calculators](https://www.google.com?q=css%20specificity%20calculator) available online and you can see that `a:hover` has a specificity of `0011`, while `#feed a:hover` has `0111`.

Comment: my type of answer :)

Comment: Thanks for typing out the suspicions I already had regarding the problem after reading the article in the comments. This makes it clear to me, thank you! I will use the specific selector as long as it doesn't become unmaintainable. Otherwise, adding !important after the style will do. ;)